# How do I skip a query if the variable is null in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

I am trying to skip a query if the object is not there but it seem to not work and I would like to know if there is any solution for this.

Here is my query

```
graphql(GET_UBO_DECLARATIONS, {
    name: "getUboDeclarations",
    options: () => ({
      fetchPolicy: "network-only"
    })
  }),
  graphql(GET_UBOS, {
    name: "getUbos",
    skip: props =>
      !props.getUboDeclarations ||
      !props.getUboDeclarations.getUboDeclarationsForThisUser,
    options: props => ({
      fetchPolicy: "network-only",
      variables: {
        _id: props.getUboDeclarations.getUboDeclarationsForThisUser._id
      }
    })
  }),
```

`props.getUboDeclarations.getUboDeclarationsForThisUser` return null so it should be `false` and query skiped

Comment: are both graphql queries in same compose?

Comment: @PiyushBhati yes

Comment: You're saying it's not being skipped because it's blowing up with a TypeError, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the `skip` as much as the `variables` -- there's no guarantee around the order these options are evaluated so even if the `skip` evaluates to `true`, the `options` function may still be called. If it is called and `props.getUboDeclarations.getUboDeclarationsForThisUser` is in fact `null`, you'll get a TypeError because you're trying to read the `_id` property of a `null` value. The fix is to modify `variables` to account for the possible null:

```
variables: {
  _id: props.getUboDeclarations && props.getUboDeclarations.getUboDeclarationsForThisUser && props.getUboDeclarations.getUboDeclarationsForThisUser_id
}
```

Note that you can use something like lodash's `get` to make these null guard clauses easier to deal with.

Comment: Thank you for this. Really good explanation and good tip in the end.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are missing `where` in your `getUbos` query.

```
graphql(GET_UBO_DECLARATIONS, {
name: "getUboDeclarations",
options: () => ({
  fetchPolicy: "network-only"
})
}),
graphql(GET_UBOS, {
name: "getUbos",
skip: props =>
  !props.getUboDeclarations ||
  !props.getUboDeclarations.getUboDeclarationsForThisUser,
options: props => ({
  fetchPolicy: "network-only",
  variables: {
    where: {// this is missing
       _id: props.getUboDeclarations.getUboDeclarationsForThisUser._id
    }
  }
})
```

}),